# John Conway's Game of Life - Basic implementation in C

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm

> John Conway's Game of Life - Set of Rules
>
> 1. Any live cell with fewer than two live neighbours dies, as if caused by underpopulation.
> 2. Any live cell with more than three live neighbours dies, as if by overcrowding.
> 3. Any live cell with two or three live neighbours lives on to the next generation.
> 4. Any dead cell with exactly three live neighbours becomes a live cell.

I've been working on implementing John Conway's Game of Life in C for the past few hours . What I'm trying to do is display the status of a board after K successive iterations . As input, I use the number of lines (int n ) and columns (int m) for a two-dimensional array, the components of the array (1 for live, 0 for dead)  and the number of generations (K) .

I've managed to successfully implement the game using a plane approach.

[image]

What is meant by plane approach you can see in the left grid, where we check the neighbours of the black boxes to the N,NW,S,SW and so on . My algorithm works just fine for this, the 'life' function looks like this . For this to work, I've surrounded both marginal lines/columns with zeros.

```
void life(int a[100][100],int n,int m) {
  //Copies the main array to a temp array so changes can be entered into a grid
  //without effecting the other cells and the calculations being performed on them.
  int count;
  copy(a, temp, n ,m);
  for(int i = 1 ; i <=n ; i++) {
    for(int j = 1; j <= m; j++) {
      count = 0;
      count = a[i-1][j] + a[i][j-1] + a[i+1][j] + a[i][j+1] + a[i-1][j+1]
        + a[i+1][j-1] + a[i-1][j-1] + a[i+1][j+1];
      //The cell dies.
      if(count < 2 || count > 3)
        temp[i][j] = 0;
      //The cell stays the same.
      if(count == 2)
        temp[i][j] = a[i][j];
      //The cell either stays alive, or is "born".
      if(count == 3)
        temp[i][j] = 1;
    }
  }
  //Copies the completed temp array back to the main array.
  copy(temp, a, n ,m);
}
```

But on the second grid we notice that each box has exactly eight neighbours, regardless of its position on the map. To check all the neighbours in this way, I'm supposed to use a toroidal approach.

But I can't really grasp the concept, I mean I understand what a torrus is, but I just can't find a way to implement and write in code a checking function for this...

These being said, can someone please explain how to think and maybe write such an approach ?

Comment: Try using the `%` operator to wrap around limits: `x %= 100` will turn `100` into `0`, `101` into `1`, etc.

Comment: use the modulus operator in the array indices: `a[i-1][j+1]` --> `a[(i+n-1)%n][(j+m+1)%m]`

Comment: The downvote seems most unjust, why not shed some wisdom if part of my post is inadequate, and suggest how I can improve it?

Comment: First, does your first plane approach really work?  It looks to me like you are reading from array indices [100] and [101] which do not exist.  I am assuming `n` and `m` are 100.  Once you figure out the plane approach edge cases, you might have an idea on how to handle the wraparound (torus) case.

Comment: (In titles/headlines referring to programming (languages), do not use [BASIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BASIC) lightly:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When dealing with a problem that you don't understand, it is often easier to try solving a simpler problem first.

In the game of life you have a 2 dimensional grid.  What if we made things simpler by only having one dimension.  What if you only had a single row instead of a grid?  How would you handle making the first and last elements of the row neighbors?

Comment: This is neither a critique of the question nor a request for clarification. It is a very good answer to the question, and to many other questions the OP may face in the future.

Comment: Thank you for your and everyone else's effort to explain, but I still don't get it. I just can't wrap my mind around this toroidal approach, it's terribly frustrating..

Comment: Let me go one step further in trying to help you understand it.  Maybe doing something physical will help.
Take a piece of 8 by 11 inch paper and tear it into a narrow strip.  Now draw 9 vertical lines on the narrow strip and fill the space between the lines with an index number, starting at 0.  That represents your 1 dimensional array of 10 elements.
How can you rearrange the paper so that all of the elements are adjacent?
I'm not directly providing you with the answer because I think you'll understand the torus approach better if you figure it out from what I've given you.